# Highlighting text (user input)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to involve coding a simple component to highlight substrings of text provided by a user

but I'm getting errors when I'm trying to get the value from a text-area and compare it against a input area

```
import React from "react";

const Highlighted = ({ text = "", highlight = "" }) => {
  if (!highlight.trim()) {
    return <span>{text}</span>;
  }
  const regex = new RegExp(`(${highlight})`, "gi");
  const parts = text.split(regex);

  return (
    <span>
      {parts.filter(String).map((part, i) => {
        return regex.test(part) ? (
          <mark key={i}>{part}</mark>
        ) : (
          <span key={i}>{part}</span>
        );
      })}
    </span>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const text = <textarea data-testid="source-text" />;
  const highlight = <input data-testid="search-term" />;
  return (
    <>
      <Highlighted
      text={text}
      highlight={highlight}
    />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const text = <textarea data-testid="source-text" />;
const highlight = <input data-testid="search-term" />;
```

You cannot get values directly from JSX.

Instead of doing that, you can set `useState` for those variables (as states), and use `onChange` on these input fields for updating the states with input values.

```js
const Highlighted = ({ text = "", highlight = "" }) => {
  if (!highlight.trim()) {
    return <span>{text}</span>;
  }
  const regex = new RegExp(`(${highlight})`, "gi");
  const parts = text.split(regex);

  return (
    <span>
      {parts.filter(String).map((part, i) => {
        return regex.test(part) ? (
          <mark key={i}>{part}</mark>
        ) : (
          <span key={i}>{part}</span>
        );
      })}
    </span>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('')
  const [highlight, setHighlight] = React.useState('')
  return (
    <div>
    <textarea data-testid="source-text" onChange={(event) => setText(event.target.value)}/>
    <input data-testid="search-term" onChange={(event) => setHighlight(event.target.value)}/>
    <Highlighted
      text={text}
      highlight={highlight}
    />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```